# Passing custom date/time inside bash command running in Python3

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to run a python program/package with some custom bash command inside py3. Rest of the pure python code is working but this bash command is giving me lot of pain in getting an output files. Currently, I am using this command inside Python 3 (py file)

```
import os
os.system("now=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)")
os.system("-d biden_${now}.txt --function=linear -f trump_${now}.txt")
os.system("-i trump_${now}.txt --daemon --quiet --port 8022")
```

but in output directory I must get files with names like

```
biden_2021-01-03.txt and trump_2021-01-03.txt
```

which must includes today's date. When I am trying to do this via fix file names, it performs the required operations of python program/package but when I am trying to make it customise based on date wise file operations, it is just giving me files with names:

```
biden_.txt and trump_.txt
```

but with no dates in it. Can someone please guide me where I am doing wrong or any easier solution to achieve this? I am running this on/using Python 3.5.3, Debian GNU/Linux 9 Operating system, Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64, Architecture: x86-64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system` creates a new subshell for each call, so the `now` env variable is not available in the subsequent calls.

You can either directly generate the date string in Python and pass it as a format string:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().date().isoformat()
os.system("-d biden_{now}.txt --function=linear -f trump_{now}.txt".format(now=now))
os.system("-i trump_{now}.txt --daemon --quiet --port 8022".format(now=now))
```

Or you can put the `now` variable in Python's environment and reference it inside the `os.system` call:

```
os.environ['now'] = datetime.datetime.now().date().isoformat()
os.system("-d biden_${now}.txt --function=linear -f trump_${now}.txt")
os.system("-i trump_${now}.txt --daemon --quiet --port 8022")
```

Comment: Both solution worked for me perfectly. For instance, I am using the second solution here then how I can include 2nd custom variable. I tried doing two variables like -- #os.environ['now'] = datetime.datetime.now().date().isoformat()  AND for next command port number 8022 is now a variable, so I have added a function which is giving me a new port no. everytime... say from #os.environ['newport'] = addr[1] and then I have tried to do #os.system("-i trump_${now}.txt --daemon --quiet --port ${newport}") but it is throwing errors.

Answer (score 3):

If this is just for the filenames you could achieve it with the `datetime` module.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> today_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>>> cmd = f"-d biden_{today_date}.txt --function=linear -f trump_{today_date}.txt"
>>> cmd
'-d biden_2021-01-03.txt --function=linear -f trump_2021-01-03.txt'
```

Comment: This solution worked fine for me for saving the file. But when I run this with 2nd custom variable (say {port_number} and {today_date}) at the same time in single bash command, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The os.system calls are spawning in new shell. See samples

Sample1:

```
os.system("now=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)")
os.system("echo $now")
```

Sample2:

```
os.system("now=$(date +%Y-%m-%d); echo $now")
2021-01-03
```

You can combine into something like

```
os.system("echo \"Your file name is biden`date +%Y-%m-%d`.txt\"")
Your file name is biden2021-01-03.txt
```

But your time will slowly shift, depending how long your processing will take.

If you do not want your time to drift, but to match your start time, use python date as in meantime [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65555421/10438242) by [abc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359058/abc)

Comment: What will be connection with time if I am just considering the date here? The processing would not take more than 30 to 40minutes max. Is there anything affected if time is not considered here?